# query related posts in a custom post type by a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to display related posts by a custom taxonomy and only have the solution for related posts using a category.

```
    $orig_post = $post;
    global $post;
    $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
    if ($categories) {
    $category_ids = array();
    foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;

    $args=array(
    'category__in' => $category_ids,
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'posts_per_page'=> 4, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
    'caller_get_posts'=>1
    ); 

    $my_query = new wp_query($args);  
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {  
    echo '<div id="relatedposts" class="clearfix"><h4>Related Posts</h4><ul>';  
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) {  
    $my_query->the_post();  
    ?>  

    <?php  
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>  
    <li><div class="relatedthumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
    <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div></a>
    </div>
    </li> 
    <?php }  
    ?>  

<?
}
echo '</ul></div>';
}
}
$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query();
```

The following code only works for post types with registered category not custom taxonomy types.

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but it seems like the `caller_get_posts` argument is deprecated: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Sticky_Post_Parameters

Comment: Posting self-answered questions that describe a solution to a problem or issue is great, so thanks for that! Unfortunately, it is difficult to tell from your question exactly what the issue/problem being solved is. Can you rewrite your question to describe the issue/problem better?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

okay now i found the code that makes it able to use a custom taxonomy to show related posts for a custom post type.

1. $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'product_tags', 'string'); is the custom taxonomy in which you should put to query all the tags in your custom post type
2. 'post_type' => 'products' is the custom post type in which calls all the custom tags created in the custom taxonomy in which in this case is product_tags

Input this code anywhere inside your loop or query to show all posts within your custom post type. This does not filter your custom post type based on different tags. This shows all the tags within your custom post type, which in this case is products.

```
//Get array of terms
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'product_tags', 'string');
//Pluck out the IDs to get an array of IDS
$term_ids = wp_list_pluck($terms,'term_id');

//Query posts with tax_query. Choose in 'IN' if want to query posts with any of the terms
//Chose 'AND' if you want to query for posts with all terms
  $second_query = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'products',
      'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_tags',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'terms' => $term_ids,
                        'operator'=> 'IN' //Or 'AND' or 'NOT IN'
                     )),
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
      'orderby' => 'rand',
      'post__not_in'=>array($post->ID)
   ) );

//Loop through posts and display...
    if($second_query->have_posts()) {
     while ($second_query->have_posts() ) : $second_query->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="single_related">
           <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'related_sm', array('alt' => get_the_title()) ); ?> </a>
            <?php } else { ?>
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <?php } ?>
       </div>
   <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();
   }
```

okay now this code helps solve the issue with using custom post types to filter in a custom taxonomy. For example, I had project as my taxonomy and for custom post type. When i add different tags to each project they create a tagportfolio taxonomy in which add all the taxonomies and queries them.

Comment: Awesome, Almost saved my life, thank you so much for the super easy solution.